# Cannot render React page because of 404 error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Good day!
I tried to create my first React-application.
This is package.json:

```
 {
   "name": "budget",
   "version": "1.0.0",
   "scripts": {
     "start": "lite-server"
   },
  "devDependencies": {
    "lite-server": "^2.2.1"
  }
}
```

html-page:

```
<html>
   <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8"/>
     <title>Menu</title>
  </head>
<body>
     <div id="app"></div>

    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.25.0/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/babel" src="MainMenu.jsx"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

jsx:

```
 class MainMenu extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Date</td>
            <td>Operation</td>
            <td>Amount</td>
            <td>Item of expenditure</td>
            <td>Balance</td>
        </tr>
     </table>
     }
 }

ReactDOM.render(
     <MainMenu/>,
     document.getElementById("app")
);
```

When I trying to start app, I receive page with only title: Cannot GET /

In developer tools I see the following error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Just in case the structure of project:

[image: project_structure]

Comment: Are you following a tutorial for your first react app? Or are you just winging it?

Comment: I did not use any tutorials

Comment: Do you have an `index.html` file in your root directory? I would expect *lite-server* to pick it up for '/' path

Comment: No, I have not index.html